# Drawing with bearing and distance in QGIS

Tags: qgis

Is there a way to draw with bearing and distance within QGIS? I need to draw easements in QGIS and they are provided to us in the following format.

[image]

I've come across a plugin called "Azimuth and Distance" but it seems a bit clunky and doesn't seem to work properly (I could be using it wrong). The other option I have is draw it in CAD but that adds extra steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QGIS (3.28 used here) the **Advanced Digitizing Tools** this is built-in (no plugin required).

set your CRS Projection correctly first!

[image]

https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#advanced-digitizing

Shortcuts
Ctrl + or Alt + Shift +

https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#the-advanced-digitizing-panel

Comment: I wasn't to sure how that tool worked with DMS but i am seeing that you convert the DMS to DD. Thank you for your help.