Find point that is a certain distance from another point in QGIS
I am new to QGIS. I am trying to digitise polygons on a historical map based on descriptions. For example:

Commencing at that point on the southern boundary line of the territory of Colorado where the meridian of longitude 107° W. from Greenwich crosses the same; running thence N. with said meridian to a point 15 miles due N. of where said meridian intersects the fortieth parallel of N. latitude; thence due W. to the western boundary line of said territory; thence S. with said western boundary line of said territory to the southern boundary line of said territory; thence E. with said southern boundary line to the place of beginning.

In order to digitise polygons, I am creating the points, converting to lines, and converting to polygons. In the example above, I am able to obtain the first point (37, -107), but I am not sure how to calculate the point '15 miles due North'. Is there a way to create such a point in QGIS? I have tried QChainage (but it does not work due to unit conversion). In the interests of replication I would prefer not to make the point manually using the measure tool.

Umm, you probably only think you can obtain the first point. Geodesy has changed over the years, so depending on how "historic" the map is, the location of {-107,37} could be well away from where we put it in modern times. Finding a function to solve the "first problem of geodesy" aka "Direct" or "Forward" is trivial compared with determining the actual start point in WGS84.

See here how to create a point with a certain bearing and distance from an existing point: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/473075/88814

You can use expressions.
If you only want to visualize the point you can add a symbol layer. The actual point feature is the yellow square. If you need the points as a layer, for example to snap to you can use Geometry by expression.
My layer is in coordinate system EPSG:4326. I reproject from 4326 (with degrees as units) to 3006 (meters), you need to pick some suitable coordinate system for your area (1609 m is one mile).
project(transform($geometry, 4326, 3006), 1609, radians(180))


